# Trying to add functionality to a button

Tags: java, button, label, windowbuilder

Ive created a gui using windowbuilder, in it i have a button and label, my hope is that on click i can change the labels text, I am not sure how to do this and the currents configuration (below) is the one i was told to use but it seems to fail to work. I know its very basic but this is only my third day writing java, thnaks for the help

```
        JButton button1 = new JButton(".............");
        button1.setForeground(Color.RED);
        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JLabel clickit.SetText("you clicked it");
```

Comment: `JLabel clickit.SetText("you clicked it");` (method name is wrong (should start with small `s`), and there's no `new` keyword for the reference variable clickit, etc) is probably the problem. Since this is your third day, why go straight into GUI?

Comment: try `button1.setText(String text)` instead of  `JLabel clickit.SetText("you clicked it");`